# Why does the branch cut for log(1+z), cutting away the negative axis, start at -1?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am really confused about this concept.

Is it because from -1 to 0, the inputs (1+z) are just viewed as inputs that aren't actually from the negative axis at all, and so log(1+z) is well-defined and continuous on (-1,0]?  I don't see the single-valuedness on (-1,0], though.  Shouldn't log(1+z) jump by a $2\pi i$ term, on (-1,0]?

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: If $z\in(-1,0)$, then $1+z$ is positive and so its log is the usual logarithm on positive reals.

Comment: Ah, of course :-(  Thanks so much @Rahul,

Comment: Hi @Rahul, so, the real intention of my asking this question yesterday was to hopefully understand why the branch cut for $\sqrt{zsin(z)}$ starts at $-\pi$ and to $\infty$ and at $+\pi$ to $\infty$.  Is the idea from the simpler example of $log(1+z)$ transferable to $\sqrt{zsin(z)}$ at all?  Or is the reasoning different?  Here I am looking at $\large \frac{sin(z)}{z}$ and defining it to be $1$ at $z=0$, so that $\sqrt{zsin(z)}$ is defined and analytic in a neigbhorhood of zero, and so the function does not develop a singularity until at $z= +/- \pi$.  What do you think?  Thanks Rahul,

Comment: So basically, my confusion lingers: why does the branch cut for $\sqrt{zsin(z)}$ start at $\pi$?  Doesn't it have to start at the origin $z=0$?  Thanks @Rahul,

Comment: Ooh actually what Tim Raczkowski wrote below in his answer is helpful - to think of it as $log(w)$, and  the branch cut starts at where $w=0$, which is at +/- $\pi$.  Please feel free to comment, if you'd like to add anything, or especially if you think that I've missed the point on something.  Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w=1+z$.  Now, the branch cut for $\log w$ starts at $w=0$. So, the branch cut for $\log(1+z)$ starts where $1+z=0$. In other words, where $z=-1$.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @TimRaczkowski :-)